# tidyverse code equivalent of exp(mean(log(murders$population))) in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working through the book "Introduction to Data Science" by Rafael Irizarry and I am stuck on one of the exercises. I need to write the tidyverse equivalent of `exp(mean(log(murders$population)))` using the dot operator. I started with `murders %>% log(population)` but it says that the object population not found. I think the problem I'm running into is that I am not pulling from the data frame correctly but could use some direction. Which I think is the point of using the dot but that attempt `murders %>% log(.$population)` also didnt work.

```
> exp(mean(log(murders$population)))
[1] 3675209
> murders %>% log(population)
Error in function_list[[k]](value) : object 'population' not found
> murders %>% log(.$population)
Error in Math.data.frame(., .$population) : 
non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: state, abb, region
```

Comment: Try `murders %>% pull(population) %>% log %>% mean %>% exp`

Comment: Yep that worked and I added the dot operator to each of them. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we waant to use the functions in chain, `pull` the variable and apply the functions in chain

```
library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)
data(murders)
murders %>% 
     pull(population) %>% 
     log %>%
     mean %>% 
     exp
#[1] 3675209
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)

data(murders)

murders  %>% .$population %>% log %>% mean  %>% exp
```